# How do you evaluate inherent object methods in Javascript and express it in Big-O?

Tags: javascript, big-o

When calculating big-O notation do we also evaluate inherent javascript methods? 
If we do not, I am reasonably certain this is O(N). 
If we do how would I express his in big-O and how did you come to this conclusion?

NOTE 1: this post has been edited to change "x" to 25, the loop is fixed
NOTE 2: the string can be any size

```
// the string can be any size
while( i++ < 25) {//edited from previous post - this was formerly "x"

    regex = RegExp( MyArray[i],'g' );    
    if ( (myString.match(regex)||[]).length ){      
        myObj.push([   
            myArray[i], (myString.match(regex)||[]).length
        ]);    
        myString = myString.replace(regex,'');
    }   
}
myObj.sort(function(a, b) {return b[1] - a[1]});
```

Comment: Are you asking about the time complexity of method lookup for *inherited* methods?

Comment: @cookiemonster: No, he's asking about methods that were provided by the "framework" that you're working in. For example, if the string.match() method takes longer depending on the value of `i`, then its complexity would contribute to the complexity of this method as a whole.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: So the question is how the time complexity of functions/methods/whatever called within a section of code is factored into the overall time complexity of that code?

Comment: @cookiemonster: Yes, that's how I understand it.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior : cookiemonster is right, I am trying to determine if I need to include things going on behind the scenes in javascript - I haven't seen this addressed in any of the reading I have done about big-O run time complexity

Comment: @CorteoTazu: Your question doesn't really make sense anymore. As Jason Orendorff points out, Big-O is defined in relation to specific operations (comparisons, memory reads, swaps, etc.), and in relation to specific variables (string length, an integer's value, etc.) Without more information about the values in MyArray, and the starting value in myString, there's no way to know how complex any given call to match() is going to be, or how quickly that complexity would grow with regards to the string's length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do have to consider code that you didn't write.**

To properly determine the big-O (order of efficiency) of a piece of code, imagine that you replace all method calls with the actual code set up behind them.

---

In the example you gave, you have to consider the efficiency of your while loop, each call to `myString.match`, the call to `myObj.push`, the call to `myString.replace`, and the call to `myObj.sort`.

---

I'm not 100% sure of the efficiencies of each of these methods, but I'll make some guesses.

Assuming

- match is O(m),
- push is O(1),
- replace is O(m) and
- sort is O(n log n)

where `m` is `myString.length` and `n` is `myObj.length`.

then your code would be O(x * (3m + 1) + n log n)

which reduces to *approximately* **O(x*m)**

---

**EDIT**

Since your loop is now a constant number of iterations, the calculation would be O(1 * (3m + 1) + n log n)

with this edit, the new approximation is **O(n log n)** because the efficiency is dependent on the order of the sort function (as long as sort operates in *worse* than O(m) time.

Comment: The OP is asking about big-O notation, though I don't understand specifically what he's addressing. So I'm not sure what the order of evaluation has to do with it.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Wikipedia says "The letter O is used because the growth rate of a function is also referred to as *order* of the function."

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: replace and match are only O(n) with regards to the length of the strings that they deal with, which appears unrelated to the value of `x` in this problem.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Good catch. I will adjust my values.

Comment: @LukeWillis I made an adjustment, x will always be 25, it myArray.length-1 which holds the lowercase chars of the alphabet. the string is x length

Comment: @CorteoTazu I edited my answer based on your adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O notation is always talking about the amount *of something*, and you can specify which "something" you're talking about. Sometimes it's really important to do so. When someone says "merge sort is O(*n* log *n*)", they mean it **performs O(*n* log *n*) comparisons** and O(*n* log *n*) copies, where *n* is the number of items to sort. If comparisons and copies always run in constant time, then the result will be that the merge sort **runs in O(*n* log *n*) time**. But that's not always true! String comparisons, for instance, aren't constant-time.

Your program makes 25 calls to myString.match(). It **performs O(1) `match`es**.

Each match takes an amount of time that depends on the regular expression. It could be O(*n*) where *n* is the length of the string. It could be worse; especially bad regular expressions can take exponential time, O(2<sup>*n*</sup>), to run.

Suppose all the regular expressions run in O(*n*) time. Then this program **runs in O(*n*) time**, where *n* is the length of `myString`.